# To hyphenate or not to hyphenate: Grammatically correct or aesthetically pleasing text?

Tags: copywriting, wording, grammar

Marketing is asking us (Development) to change some UI text to be grammatically incorrect. Specifically, they're basically asking to remove hyphens from [compound adjectives](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/adjectives_compound_adjectives.htm) (e.g., 'thirty-foot wingspan', 'late-fee messages').

That would change the meaning of the text. But maybe 95% of users don't know better. In which case, there's an argument to be made that grammatically incorrect equates to a better user experience.

And there is one case where I myself have opted not to use hyphens even though they are called for, grammatically speaking. Example:

"Show credit card transactions"

I'm curious if anyone else has settled on a rule for this. Or if there's a style guide that has good guidance on this question.

Comment: I see you are in the US. So presumably your target audience is just in the US ?

Comment: @PhillipW, correct

Comment: I would think that ‘ late-fee messages’ and ‘ late fee messages’ is not the same? (But English is not my first language)

Comment: This just makes me happy that in German, *Kreditkartentransaktionsanzeige* does not have this problem ;)

Comment: @Stefan A ‘late fee message’ would have me wondering what a ‘fee message’ is, and why it would be late.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Associated Press Stylebook](https://www.apstylebook.com/), commonly adopted by publications and marketing departments, used to require hyphens between compound adjectives but [changed its guidelines in 2019](https://www.cjr.org/language_corner/associated-press-hyphen.php):

> We updated our hyphen guidance this year to say no hyphen is needed in
> a compound modifier if the modifier is commonly recognized as one
> phrase, and if the meaning is clear and unambiguous without the
> hyphen. One example is first quarter touchdown.

However, the [Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/search.epl?q=compound), another widely adopted styleguide, still recommends using hyphens for compound adjectives.

As a former marketing copywriter, I can attest that using hyphens with compound adjectives often confused content reviewers, who would remove them even though they were "stylistically" correct. Your marketing department may have come to the conclusion that the average reader doesn't understand why the hyphens are there and therefore decided to no longer use them.

Comment: Thanks. As it turns out, they are using the AP style guide you referenced. I think the AP's guidance makes sense, and matches my own decision. I think they missed the part where it says "commonly recognized as one phrase, *and* if the meaning is clear and unambigous", and instead took away from the guide that hyphens for compound adjectives should be avoided.

Comment: And _of course_ their example, "first quarter touchdown", is a garden-path phrase that demonstrates exactly why hyphens are courteous to the reader.

Comment: It's *first quarter-touchdown*, right? (I'm not a native speaker and don't play baseball…)

Comment: @Bergi It's "first-quarter touchdown"